# Cannot import: "from trello import TrelloClient" py-trello and trello packages (replit)

Tags: python, trello, replit

To be simple, I couldn't import py-trello bcs there is also a package named trello.
when I run

```
from trello import TrelloClient
```

replit thinks that I'm working on python **trello** package and installs trello package. And then my code gives error like "cannot import TrelloClient". But actually I'm trying to work on **py-trello**

I tried to add a requirements.txt file to my workspace but when I run the main.py file it automatically downloads the trello package.
How can I import py-trello package instead of trello package?
It works perfectly fine on my local workspace because I only have py-trello. So it's importing py-trello.
But the automatic download system of replit does not let me import py-trello.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import trello #upm package(py-trello)`

> When you add a package by importing, we attempt to guess what package
> you want based on the modules you are importing. In most languages
> this is a direct correspondence, but in Python sometimes we can get it
> wrong. You can directly request a package by specifying the package
> directly on the import line.

Read in [documentation](https://docs.repl.it/repls/packages)

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that and I didn't even know how to search for this:)

Comment: You're most welcome @mustafayavuz happy coding from Australia.